# Django : Filter bills with client name in the same page without reloading

Tags: ajax, django

in my view I have the list of `bills` , and I need to add a field in order to filter the list by `client` as bellow :

[image]

so that if I choose client `rgg` it will get only show `bill` of that client.
To do so, I need some orientation if I should do it with `Ajax call` , because I dont want to reload the page each time I change my choice.
I really need to know the best way to do such thing.

Thank You so much for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not mention if you are using a javascript component for the table allready.

If not, you can search for one that meets your needs (there are a lot of them). For example, [DataTables](https://datatables.net/).

Or you can create your own filtering logic, like [this w3schools page](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_table.asp) shows.

Comment: I dont use any js for my table. I guess I will go with w3schools page. Thank you sooo much for your answer. you helped me a lot.